# How to specify oracle odbjc.jar in Liquibase ant configuration

Tags: ant, liquibase, ojdbc

I have following ant configuration:

```
<project name="pcebuild" basedir="." default="updateDatabase" xmlns:liquibase="antlib:liquibase.integration.ant" >
    <taskdef resource="liquibase/integration/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:liquibase.integration.ant">
        <classpath path="c:\Users\artur.skrzydlo\Documents\liquibase-3.3.2-bin\liquibase.jar"/>
    </taskdef> 

  <property name="liquiChangeLogFile" value="${basedir}/liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml"/>
  <property name="db.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="db.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@websph:1521:XE"/>

  <target name="updateDatabase" description="Updates database with new changes using Liquibase">
    <liquibase:updateDatabase  changeLogFile="${liquiChangeLogFile}" >
        <liquibase:database  driver="${db.driver}" url="${db.url}" user="${db.user}" password="${db.pasword}"/>
    </liquibase:updateDatabase>
  </target>

 </project>
```

After running this task I get an error :

```
 Class not found: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

According to documentation  :

> driver       The fully qualified class name of the JDBC driver.

I suppose that this error may rise because there is no place where I place classpath to my ojdbc.jar file. I am able to run this update command from command line, however there I can specify "classpath" argument which point to my ojdbc.jar file. And I don's see any place in this ant task definition where could i place it such a path. How can I do this ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think adding the jdbc.jar to the classpath of the taskdef should work.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to add ojdbc.jar with that but without success. I've tried it again an suprisingly it works now. I had to made some mistake in previous try. Anyway thanks.  Now I have a new issue because I get a new error :  Unable to create Liquibase database instance. A JDBC error occurred. Is there a log file for a liquibase ?

Comment: try ant -verbose updateDatabase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `<liquibase:updateDatabase>` tag you can have a `classpathref` attribute. So I have something like this:

```
<path id="driver.classpath">
    <filelist files="${classpath}" />
</path>
...
<liquibase:updateDatabase 
        databaseref="main-schema" 
        changelogfile="${changeLogFile}"
        classpathref="driver.classpath"
        logLevel="debug"
    >
...
```

And `${classpath}` is an Ant property, set in a properties file:

```
classpath: /Users/me/place/lib/classes12.jar
```

Comment: Yest it works, however I've added classpathref in taskdef tag. My path definition now looks like this `   <path id="driver.classpath">
       <filelist dir="c:\lib" >
        <file name="ojdbc.jar" /> 
        <file name="liquibase.jar" /> 
       </filelist>    
   </path>`